# packages will not load

Tags: packages, contexts

I have a package at `/Users/me/Desktop/Mathematica/MyPackages/SamplePackage.m`. It looks like this:

```
BeginPackage["SamplePackage`"]

bruh::usage = "bruh[ x] computes a simple function."
bruhpriv::usage = "bruhpriv[x] gives 5."

bruh[x_] := Module[{y}, y = x^2;
  y + 1]

Begin["`Private`"]
bruhpriv[x_] := 5
End[]
EndPackage[]
```

Obviously I have no use for this, I am just trying to make a freaking package load. Anyways, if I open the file SamplePackage.m in Mathematica and run it then open a new notebook, I can access both `bruh` and `bruhpriv` by their short and long names. Further, SamplePackage' is in the list of

> $Packages

and SamplePackage' is also in the

> $ContextPath

bruh[4] gives 17 like it should, etc. However, if I do anything but run the file SamplePackage.m it won't work. I use `AppendTo[$Path,the folder I want]` and if I do <<SamplePackage.m it runs with no error message. If I do `Get["SamplePackage.m"]` it runs with no error message. I know it is finding the file because if I remove the AppendTo line I get the file no found error, as expected.

So after I do <<SamplePackage.m it does not matter what I do I cannot use bruh[x] or bruhpriv[x]. Typing them in just echoes back the input. Further, SamplePackage' is not in

> $Packages

or

> $Context Path

The only way to get the functions is to open the file and run the lines. What am I doing wrong?

EDIT: IMAGE IN RESPONSE TO MURRAY
[image]

Comment: Your description is a bit vague. Can you give an accurate and complete, step-by-step description of what you did? "This is what I did, step-by-step, in full detail. This is what I expected to happen. This is what happened." Without this information, people will simply tell you that it works for them (as you can already see). I expect there is some detail that you may assume to be unimportant (and so did not mention) but is actually causing the problem.

Comment: Be sure to include complete, runnable commands, with actual full paths (not edited examples). Also include the output of ``FindFile["SamplePackage`"]``.

Comment: so I finally got it to work, I realized when I ran `FindFile["SamplePackage.m"]` it failed. I'm not sure what I did wrong before but I added the file to the `$Path` and then ran <<SamplePackage.m and it worked. I could have sworn I properly added the file to the path before. Whatever, it works now!

Comment: I think part of my error was that Mathematica did not search subdirectories in the path list which I assumed it would. perhaps before I had it in a subdirectory. this time I added the direct parent directory to the path and it worked

Comment: No, it does not search subdirectories. This could have been spotted immediately if you show a complete example, with actual paths, as I asked.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

**One way:**

```
   AppendTo[$Path, "~/Desktop/Mathematica/MyPackages"]
   Get["SamplePackage.m"]

   bruh[3]
(* 10 *)
```

**Nicer way:**

1. Create a new folder `SamplePackage` inside
   `/Desktop/Mathematica/MyPackages`.
2. Move `SamplePackage.m` into that new folder.
3. In `/Desktop/Mathematica/MyPackages/SamplePackage` create a new subfolder `Kernel`.
4. In that new subfolder `Kernel`, put the following little package `init.m` whose contents consist of just the single cell: `` Get["SamplePackage`SamplePackage`"] ``

Now again append `` Get["SamplePackage`SamplePackage`"] `` to `$Path` and just load the package by:

```
<< SamplePackage`
```

**Nicest way**

Do the same thing as for "Nicer Way" *except* put the whole folder `SamplePackage` into the `Applications` subfolder of `$UserBaseDirectory` (which under macOS, for example, would be `~/Library/Mathematica/Applications`).

This way, you no longer have to use `AppendTo[$Path,...]`. Now you simple use:

```
<< SamplePackage`
```

Comment: More generally, `AppendTo[$Path, FileNameJoin[{$HomeDirectory, "MyPackages"}]];`

Comment: @murray for some reason I can load the files in all three cases you provided but I still cannot use the function bruh[x]...I'm not sure what else I could be doing wrong. Is it a Mathematica error or maybe something I did? Any other ideas? I can provide pictures and video if it helps.

Comment: @Brandon: How do you know you can "load" the packages? What happens if, after doing so, you evaluate `?bruh` ? And if you evaluate `$ContextPath`, is `SamplePackage` in the list?

Comment: @Brandon: Another thought: Is the contents of your `SamplePackage.m` file inside an Initialization cell? See by opening the file in Mathematica and inspect its cell bracket or select the cell bracket and use the menu selection Cell > Cell Properties to see that "Initialization cell" is checked. If not, check that and re-save the file.

Comment: @Murray Check out the edit I posted. Am I doing something wrong? I must be but like I can't figure it out!!! And I believe it loads it because it echoes nothing, whereas if I specificy a file that either doesn't exist or that isn't in `$Path`, then I get `$Failed`, Get: cannot open packagename. I also tried the initialization cell for both the sample package.m and for the notebook I am working in, but it didn't seem to make a difference.

Comment: One clue may be the following. So I did the "nicest way" and put it in the Mathematica/applications directory and I get no error when I run `<<SamplePackage'` but when I run `<<SamplePackage.m` I get an error. Before I tried your method, when I had it in the folder on my desktop, I'm pretty sure that they both worked. I assume this must somehow be significant. Bear with me haha im new to Mathematica!

Comment: @Brandon: Yes, that is exactly the behavior to be expected with the  "nicest way": `<<SamplePackage.m` fails but `<<SamplePackage` loads the package.