# Can't load Classes package

Tags: packages

This is a followup question to [packages will not load](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/224284/packages-will-not-load).

I can get SamplePackage to load by doing <<SamplePackage.m or <<SamplePackage' but I cannot get TMPClasses.m package to load, which I took from 'The Mathematica Programmer' by Maeder. Initially, TMPClasses.m was in ...Applications/myPackages/ and wouldn't load. I had myPackages in the search path. Since SamplePackage would work I tried to make the situation as symmetric as possible by renaming myPackages folder to TMPClasses, the same name as the package. The SamplePackage.m file is in a folder named SamplePackage. Except for the contents of the files themselves and the order the folders are placed in the search path I cannot think of any other asymmetries between the two situations. Any ideas on why this won't work? See the images below to see what I tried as well as the file structure.[image: This is what I tried]

[image]

As you can see, both files can be found:
[image]

As was suggested to me in the previous question I posted, for both packages I tried making a Kernel directory in the same directory as the .m file. In the Kernel directory I placed an init.m file with the contents `Get["SamplePackage'SamplePackage'"]` or `Get["TMPClasses'TMPClasses'"]`. After doing this, SamplePackage still loaded properly, and I was able to access the functions, and TMPClasses still would not load.

Comment: Keep things simple. Packages should be placed in `$UserBaseDirectory/Applications`, and *not* in a subdirectory of `$UserBaseDirectory/Applications` (at least not until you have a full understanding of what that does). Do not create any `Kernel` directories. That is for package authors who create multi-file packages. You should not do that when you simply want to install a package.

Comment: `Get["somefile"]` will evaluate the contents of the file returned by `FindFile["somefile"]`. This is what loading means. If `Classes` is not defined, then most like the file did not have a definition for `Classes` within. Double-check the contents of the exact file returned by `FindFile`.

Comment: There are some anomalies in what you show in the screenshot: `$Path` appears to be the first evaluation, yet it contains paths that should not be there by default (such as your `SamplePackage` directory). Did you add something to your `init.m`? Do not do this: it is not necessary and every modification you make (but do not mention) makes it harder for us to debug your problem.

Comment: Keep things simple, and try to give a complete and concise description of the problem. Be sure to include a minimal example where you mention every detail.  Last time you neglected to mention that you put your files in subdirectories and *not* on the `$Path`, which ended up wasting a lot of time.

Comment: Finally, `$Packages` is irrelevant for this problem. You do not need to bother with it. But please: explain the problem in a clear, structured way, and provide a complete minimal example: http://sscce.org/ Use the structure [I suggested here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/224284/packages-will-not-load#comment571062_224284).

Answer (score 0):

Copying the code for TMPClasses and pasting it in a new file made it work for some reason

Comment: This does not answer the question. It is just another symptom for diagnosing your problem, not a solution. Check the permissions on the package file and see if it is readable.